# Make a specific border radius CSS

Tags: css, border

I am trying to generate the pink part by border radius. If I use border radius, it start from the exact corner of the container div but as you see, there is just more than 1cm flat or solid pink and then border radius start.

[image: Check the image or sample here]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkdcx30w/ - like that?

Comment: What did you try and achieve that isn't exactly the result but... ?

Comment: What kind of an arc are you trying to achieve? A perfect circle?  Is it based on any other part of the page? (e.g. Does the slide height or width affect the arc in any way?)

Comment: We do not provide code writing service here at SO, so post the code you have that is suppose to look like the image and we'll be able to provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like those are just circles (`border-radius: 50%;`). Hit "Run code snippet" to see something similar.

```css
.big {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.small {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 3px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats not a circle . it is part of circle arc

Comment: This is how you would achieve it with border-radius. If you need help with the rest of the element, we'd need to see a larger picture.

Comment: @MoHo I suggest you to read this :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp
And try something like `border-radius: 0 45% 45% 0 / 0 100% 100% 0px;`